# Azure webjob run multiple webjobs in the same project at different frequency

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I'm new to the azure webjob. I have multiple jobs that I hope run at a different frequency. As for now, my solution is to have one single webjob as a standalone project and define the frequency of this job at project level, in the settings.job file. 
However, not sure if there is a way to have multiple jobs in the same project and we can have a one time deployment of a single project, yet have each job running at different frequency?

I looked up online, the closest one that I can find is this [page](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-have-a-single-project-to-hold-multiple-scheduled-azure-webjobs), which doesn't seems to work for me. Any help/sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we can create a settings.job file in root folder of each web job project as below.

[image]

Notice, we need to choose "Copy always"  as below

[image]

More information about settings.job file, we can refer to: [Web Job Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#webjob-types)